# jmeter: Is it possible in a thread group with 10 users, to have each request to loop for 50 times or run for 10 mins?

Tags: jmeter

jmeter: Is it possible in a thread group with 10 concurrent users, to have each request to loop for 50 times or run for 10 mins?

Requests should run in parallel.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not adding Loop Controller with loop count 50?

Answer (score 0):

In Thread Group:

```
  Number of Threads (Users): 10

  Ramp up period: 0 - so threads will be executed in parallel

  Check the Scheduler checkbox and enter Duration 600 (10 minutes in seconds)
```

Add Loop Controller with loop count 50

Your test will execute Users in parallel for maximum 10 minutes and then stopped.